# Google Play Experiment is available in wrong region

Tags: google-play, google-experiments

I've started Store listing experiment for `en-IN` English (India) language but I can see this experiment on Google Play although my device uses `en-GB` English (United Kingdom) locale.

Default Store listing language for my app is `en-US` English (United States) and `en-GB` is not listed.

Shouldn't be experiment available only for users with `en-IN` language and other English languages should fall back to default (`en-US`)? Can be this Store listing experiments distribution bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got response from Google Play Developer Support. It is Store listing bug and they are working on fix.